# linked list print/delete function bombs program

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I realize this might be a simple problem but I'm not catching it. My requirement is that I have to "4) Delete the linked list and print the list out again. (making sure its gone from memory)"

So I call the delete function and stepping through it, head should be set to NULL when the function finishes.

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*  Function:  deleteList
*  Purpose:   delete a link list
*  Arguments: head - a pointer to the first node in the linked list
*  Returns:   N/A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void deleteList(node *head)
{
   struct node *temp;

   // Loop through the list, deleting one node at a time.
   while(head != NULL)
   {
      temp = head->next;
      delete(head);
      head = temp;
   }
}
```

So when I call the print function and send in head, it should be NULL and catch on the first if statement and return to main. But it is bombing out instead.

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*  Function:  printList
*  Purpose:   prints a link list
*  Arguments: head - a pointer to the first node in the linked list
*  Returns:   N/A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void printList(node *head)
{
   if (head == NULL)
   {
       cout << "Empty List!\n";
      return;
   }

   struct node *temp;
   temp = head;

   // Loop through the list, printing one node at a time.
   while(temp->next != NULL)
   {
      cout << temp->next->element << endl;
      temp = temp->next;
   }
}
```

Now if I use the following in main it works fine. But I'd like to know what small thing im missing in the print function. Been banging my head on this for a while now so I'd thought I would step back and ask for a little guidance.

```
int main()
{
....
cout << "\n***************** DELETE LIST & PRINT ********************\n";
deleteList(head);

cout << head->element << endl; // This works and shows the list is empty.
//printList(head); // This bombs the program.
....
}
```

Thanks much.

Node is defined below:

```
struct node
{
   string   element;
   struct   node *next;
};
```

Declaring head in main:

```
struct node *head;

//creating head node.
if ((head=new(node)) == NULL)
{
   cout << "Error: Could not create head node.\n";
   return 1;
}
head->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Please show the definition of "node" and where you declare "head".

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, printList also dosen't print out the head of the list.  You could fix this by a loop more like your delete function, but printing instead of using delete.

Comment: The head is a dummy node. So no need to print it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use in main

```
deleteList(head);
```

A copy of the pointer "head", pointing to the same place, is passed as parameter.
So, if you change the variable that "head" points to, e.g.:

```
delete(head);
```

this will be visible in main(). But when you update the pointer "head" itself, e.g.:

```
head = temp;
```

The only pointer updated is the one in the scope of the function, and *not* the one in main. So now your "head" pointer in main points to a deleted variable.

To solve the issue, you could return the new place that "head" should point to, like so:

```
node *deleteList(node *head)
{
   struct node *temp;

   // Loop through the list, deleting one node at a time.
   while(head != NULL)
   {
      temp = head->next;
      delete(head);
      head = temp;
   }
   return head;
}
```

And call it with

```
head = deleteList(head);
```